# How can i fit this background in the text in this flex display

Tags: html, css, background

What can i do to this green container(the background) in the "btn" fit the text?

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(88, 194, 120);
}
```

```html
<section id="sec1">
  <a href="#" class="btn">btn</a>
</section>
```

Comment: margin:20px auto; to a ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `flex` to `inline-flex`.

```css
section {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(88, 194, 120);
}
```

```html
<section id="sec1">
  <a href="#" class="btn">btn</a>
</section>
```